# How to prove that $abd = abcd + abc'd$ for all general occassions

Tags: boolean-algebra

It is true for example that $abd = abcd + abc'd$. Each of the terms on the right part of the equation contains all the used letters.

Is there anyway to prove that any term is equal to the sum of the terms that contain it and and all the used letters at a specific statement ?

Comment: $abcd+abc'd = abd(c+c') = abd(1) = abd$.

Comment: Yes, this is called the *conjunctive normal form* of the original expression;  Wikipedia will have an article discussing it.

Comment: I am looking for a general proof. abd=abcd+abc′d is just a example to make what i am looking for more clear

Comment: What do you mean by general. Here c can have any boolean value